# I can't seem to get to get these variables to pop up in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add the variables that are created in this loop to excel, but they are not coming up, how should I get them to appear in excel.

```
For i = 1 To iT
       yi = Y0 + DeltaX * dydx(b, m, n, u, Y0, Z0)
       zi = Z0 + DeltaX * dzdx(a, p, q, Y0, Z0)
       Range(Cells(i, 5)) = DeltaX * i
       Range(Cells(i, 5)) = yi
       Range(Cells(i, 6)) = zi
       Y0 = yi
       Z0 = zi
    Next i
```

I expected them to appear in excel

Comment: Try explicitly saying which sheet the Range refers to - it will currently put them on the Active sheet. E.g. `ThisworkBook.Sheet(1).Range(!a1").Value=DeltaX * i`

Comment: Have you got an `On Error Resume Next` somewhere? That code produces an error on `Range(Cells(i, 5)) = DeltaX * i`. Try just using Range or just using Cells - define the target location correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the syntax wrong for `Range` and/or `Cells`

Use either `Range` OR `Cells` but you cannot combine them in this way without generating a runtime error. If you are not seeing that error then you must have

```
On Error Resume Next
```

somewhere in your code. That is bad practice (except in some very specific circumstances that do not apply here)

Whether you use `Range` or use `Cells` you should specify exactly which sheet you are referring to e.g.

```
ThisWorkBook.Sheet(1).Cells(i, 5) = DeltaX * i
```

Also note that this first line is superflouous as the data is immediately overwritten by the next line

```
   Range(Cells(i, 5)) = DeltaX * i
   Range(Cells(i, 5)) = yi
```